# How to use If Else Condition in Where Clause in SQL Server for Date Columns?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, where-clause

I want to use if else in where condition for Date Coulmns. Actually what i want to do is:

I have a table, which having two columns, CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate. Now what i want to check in Stored Proc is:

if LastUpdateDate is null then it will check for CreatedDate.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT isnull(SSA.UpdateDateTime, 
       isnull(SSA.CreateDateTime,'')) as LastUpdateAnswerDateTime 
from SI_SurveySiteAnswer SSA 
WHERE SSA.UpdateDateTime IS NOT NULL
```

There are other number of table in joins i am just pasting the required query only. how can i go for the check i am totally confused.

Please help me..

**UPDATED:**

I have write the below code, please confirm if it is the correct way to use If in where

```
SELECT isnull(SSA.UpdateDateTime,
       isnull(SSA.CreateDateTime,'')) as LastUpdateAnswerDateTime
from SI_SurveySiteAnswer SSA 
WHERE  SSA.UpdateDateTime = ISNULL(SSA.UpdateDateTime,SSA.CreateDateTime)
```

I think i was not able to make my requirement very clear in first go, let me explain here..

i have a survey question answer table, i want to send an email notification if question has been answered, now answer can answered in one go, in that case createddate will have value not the updateddatetime, 
Second case is:
answer is being updated in second go, then i need to check for the LastUpdateDateTime..

That's what i want to make in query.

Comment: may be u need to use of coalesce

Comment: can you provide some example.. please

Comment: I didn't get your logic u have used `WHERE SSA.UpdateDateTime IS NOT NULL` then what is need of `NULL check` for the same in `select`

Comment: @Pradeep i want to get default date value if value is null for the column even i know i have applied where condition. just for a logic trick..

Comment: You say that you want to check for `CreatedDate` if `LastUpdateDate` is null, but what is it that you want to check? The code that you have written in the `where` doesn't make sense, because if `UpdatedateTime` is not null then it will definitely be equal to itself (so you have a dummy comparison equivalent to `1=1`), and if it's null then it can't be equal to anything.

Comment: @Guffa please read my updated question, i have added the description of my requirement

Comment: @raman, Are you going to compare this CreateDate or UpdateDateTime in you store procedure's parameter or you just want to check which field contains value.

Comment: @YograjGupta just want to check if column has value .. rest logic is implemented in Code...

Comment: @raman If the real logic is implemented in code, just select both columns and sort it out in code...

Comment: @Psychemaster: That would mean that you fetch all records in the table. You would want to filter the result in the database, not in the code.

Comment: If an answer has not been provided how will it exist as a row in the answer table at all? i.e. NULL created date ==> the row hasn't been created

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any `if` / `else` functionality, just use the `or` operator to check that either is not null:

```
WHERE SSA.CreateDateTime is not null OR SSA.UpdateDateTime is not null
```

Comment: @raman: Then all the rows has an answer. The condition will filter out all records where there is no creation time and no update time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE if you want this functionality, here are some sites for your reference.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1521/the-many-uses-of-coalesce-in-sql-server/

http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull

Answer (score 0):

Try case statement.

```
SELECT isnull(SSA.UpdateDateTime,
       isnull(SSA.CreateDateTime,'')) as LastUpdateAnswerDateTime
from SI_SurveySiteAnswer SSA 
WHERE  CASE WHEN SSA.UpdateDateTime IS NULL THEN SSA.CreateDateTime 
ELSE SSA.UpdateDateTime END IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You are comparing the date with itself or null, so that is equivalent of `WHERE SSA.UpdateDateTime IS NOT NULL`, it won't consider `SSA.CreateDateTime` at all.

Comment: Hi @Guffa, i have edited the answer. I was unclear of your requirements. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

you can use `case`

```
 SELECT Isnull(SSA.updatedatetime, Isnull(SSA.createdatetime, '')) AS 
       LastUpdateAnswerDateTime 
FROM   si_surveysiteanswer SSA 
WHERE  SSA.updatedatetime = CASE 
                              WHEN SSA.updatedatetime IS NULL THEN 
                              @SSA.createdatetime 
                              ELSE SSA.updatedatetime 
                            END
```

Comment: You are comparing the date with itself or null, so that is equivalent of `WHERE SSA.UpdateDateTime IS NOT NULL`, it won't consider `SSA.CreateDateTime` at all.